# Is this plant Yucca filamentosa color?

Tags: species-identification, botany

I am trying to find the name of this plant for a while. The closest I got is Yucca filamentosa color. The leaf blades are near 4-5 inches and are almost thin(without pulp). Please help me in identifying it.
[image]

[image]

Location: Hyderabad, India.

Comment: Yucca mostly has smooth leaf  and this has spine shaiped leaf.  Yucca ussaly dont have so wide leaf. (https://www.swcoloradowildflowers.com/White%20Enlarged%20Photo%20Pages/yucca%20baccata.htm) here is some pictures of semi desert yuccas

Comment: No, not the Yucca baccata . I was thinking Yucca filamentosa color guard(http://www.missouribotanicalgarden.org/PlantFinder/PlantFinderDetails.aspx?kempercode=d184). As per the wide part, the leaf blades in my picture are around 4 inches wide.

Comment: You know i am not professional botanic so i hope you will get proper answer for this question.  But i think that yucca has smooth leaf without pulp(mostly), but agave has spike shaiped leaf with pulp.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the pulp part. The plant that I uploaded has almost no pulp in it's leaves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the picture that I posted belongs to  [Furcraea foetida 'Mediopicta'](https://www.gardenia.net/plant/Furcraea-foetida-Mediopicta). It belongs to "Agave" family like L.Diago suggested in comments.